# How to make scrollView can scroll in tvOS?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitextview, tvos

I use a UITextView to show some text content, But I find that UITextView can't scroll to show more content, so I decide to us a scrollView add textview as it's subView. But I find it doesn't work,How can I do?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
var scrollView: UIScrollView?
var textView: UITextView?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 200, height: 500))
    textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 200, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    textView?.text = "huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334huygfiuewfbjdbaskrgywfgqabsdjbaurguyfgsafhvdfjgiy3fdshfvdsfgq lieyouiegfhdskfkuwtrogfdsfsdfgwuyro8efgogfef334"
    textView?.sizeToFit()
    scrollView?.contentSize = textView!.frame.size
    scrollView?.addSubview(textView!)
    scrollView?.isScrollEnabled = true
    view.addSubview(scrollView!)
  }
}
```

Comment: textview is already a scrollview so you may don't have to , BTW try `scrollView?.contentSize = textView!.contentSize` ?

Comment: Thanks, However textView.frame.size is (1717.0, 1374.0),so it's right.

Comment: I know if everything is OK, then UITextView could scroll, but I have a try, and then failed.

Answer (score 0):

you should add panGestureRecognizer, also had trouble with not being able to scroll textView

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = true
textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
textView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
textView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [
    NSNumber(integerLiteral: UITouch.TouchType.indirect.rawValue)
]
```